# gitlab - templates -- EE only?

Tags: gitlab

I was investigating templates in Gitlab where the description field can have a predefined template. But could not find the feature in Gitlab CE. Are templates only available in Gitlab enterprise?

Comment: You mean issue templates? See e.g. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/283

Comment: Yes that is right - is this an EE feature only?

Comment: ...did you actually read the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the description templates. Users that create a new issue or merge request can select a description template (specific to a project).

You need to create a mardown file inside the .gitlab/issue_templates/ directory in your project repository. Commit and push this file to your default branch.

Then you can choose template :
[Using the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06qF0.png)

More information here : http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/description_templates.html

> With GitLab 8.11, we're bringing the ability to create multiple templates (for instance, one for feature proposals, another for bugs) to GitLab.com, GitLab CE, and EE.

Comment: So to go to the original question - is this only available in EE or in CE as well?

Comment: It's for all versions.

Comment: The templates I was looking at earlier were at
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/customization/issue_and_merge_request_template.html
I have now noticed these are EE only.
So these are GUI administered whereas the templates referred to above are file administered.

Comment: Just to clarify, as of Feb 2020; the templates themselves are available in the free community edition but you will need to manually select them when creating an issue/merge request. Setting it as default however is only available on the Starter (Self Managed) and Bronze (GitLab hosted) and up.

Answer (score 0):

The latest [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#add-default-issue-and-merge-request-templates-in-a-projects-repository) (February 2022) shows such templates for all GitLab tiers:

> ### Add default issue and merge request templates in a project’s repository
>
> In addition to defining [default issue and merge request description templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) in project settings, you can now set default templates in the `.gitlab`
> directory of a project’s repository.
> Do it by creating a `Default.md` file in the issue or merge request templates folders.
> If default templates exist in both the project’s settings and in the repository, the template in the settings
> takes precedence.
>
> Thanks for the contribution `@davebarr`!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/2557).